# What am i missing from this python 2.7 example trying it in 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code that I am working with from a book, they used 2.7 and I am using 3.8, just wondering what i am missing.

```
class EmployeeInfo:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Employee Information Data.")

    def personalInfo(self, firstName, lastName):
        self.firstName=firstName
        self.lastName=lastName

    def printPeronalInfo(self):
        print(self.firstName, " ", self.lastName, " ")


employeeName=EmployeeInfo()
employeeName.personalInfo("Virginia", "Walker")
employeeName.printPersonalInfo()
```

Employee Information Data.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "book.py", line 15, in 
    employeeName.printPersonalInfo
AttributeError: 'EmployeeInfo' object has no attribute 'printPersonalInfo'

Comment: There is typo in your method. It should be printPersonalInfo instead of printPeronalInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the spelling of the function, 's' is missing in the definition of the function (printPeronalInfo),
I ran the code and it worked fine after correction.

```
    def printPersonalInfo(self):
        print(self.firstName, " ", self.lastName, " ")
```

Output :-

```
Employee Information Data.Virginia   Walker
```

Comment: Thank you, i knew it had to be something small that i was missing.  there is so much going on here i thought it looked right but damn little mistake like that.  Thanks so much

Comment: @scd666: If VR7’s answer solved your problem, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer when you can. Also consider upvoting it. That’s how contributors gain reputation on Stack Overflow, and it helps other readers identify the best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I spot a syntax in the function definition `printPeronalInfo` instead of `printPersonalInfo`

Should do the trick

Comment: yeah it stuck out like a sore thumb when VR7 posted it

Comment: in case of doubt, like in this case, i double check my function calls using search function of the IDE or browser ;)